# Instantiate byte array from bin file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, byte, bin

I am trying to create an object in C#, for a project of mine. I need to create an object that takes in a String (path of the location of the bin file) and creates a byte array when an instance of that object is created.

I do not want to declare the size of the array, as that might lead to problems, as I will be loading different bin files every time

In a nutshell, I need to have an object that takes as input when instantiated, the String of the path of a bin file, and creates a byte array within the object.

So far I have tried to declare the byte array, without a default size, and then tried to implement it when I create the object, but I am getting an error

```cs
// Class File for the Object
namespace binMapper;

public class binFile {
    public byte[] binData {get;set;} = new byte[];

    public binFile(String pathToBinFile)
    {
the Object
        this.binData = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToBinFile);
    }
}
```

the error is shown below

> Array creation must have array size or array initializer [ObjCSharp]csharp(CS1586)

Comment: If you want to assign an array object to that property then that object MUST have a size. If you don't want to assign an array object then why are you assigning anything at all? Don't.

Comment: You don't ask two questions at once on SO. If you have two issues, you post two questions. Is that second "issue" even an issue at all? I don't see it but, if it is, you need to explain it. A comment in the code is not an explanation.

Comment: Worst case you assign it 0. Or assign it `Array.Empty<byte>();` if you don't want a magic constant.

Comment: Why are you assigning an inital value to `binData` at all when you are assigning its alue in the constructor? Even if `new byte[]` was legal, the assignment would be completely redundant.

Comment: I know this isn't codereview.se but: 1. In C# classnames and public property names should start with a capital ( => "BinFile", "BinData"). The error has been discussed above, so I'll give you just another unrelated tip: I'd not do this in the ctor. Actually, I'd make the ctor private and make a static async Factory Method, that can use async IO. A ctor cannot do that.

Comment: It is not at all clear what the actual goal is. Your `binFile` does not seem to provide any more functionality than `File.ReadAllBytes` does. If you want to save or load objects to file you should read about [serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/). Most commonly using json, or something like protobuf .net. Just avoid `BinaryFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

`File.ReadAllBytes` creates an entirely new array. Because you read the bin file in the constructor, you do not need to initalize your property with a default value. The solution would look something like this (also implementing some standard naming schemes):

```cs
namespace BinMapper;

public class BinFile
{
    public byte[] BinData { get; set; }

    public BinFile(string pathToBinFile)
    {
        this.BinData = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToBinFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You, probably, want to set an *empty* array as default value for `binData` property. Technically, you can use `new byte[0]` for this, but better approach is not creating unwanted instance, but use `Array.Empty`:

```
public class binFile {
    // I doubt that you want to set binData from outside the class
    // that's why I use "privae set"
    public byte[] binData {get; private set;} = Array.Empty<byte>();

    public binFile(String pathToBinFile)
    {
        this.binData = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToBinFile);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Does setting a value to a property, that is also set in the constructor bring any benefit?

Comment: @Jeanot Zubler: You are quite: if we set property value in constrictor, there's no need to do it in declaration. However, I treat `binFile` in the question as a problem demonstrator only. The actual `binFile` can well have several constructors, properties, methods, etc. That's why I've shown how to set an empty array as a default value.